# PHP date/time difference is giving me an extra hour

Tags: php

I'm trying to following code to get the difference in hours between 2 date/time values.
The difference should be 47.82, but the result is 48.82. I can't figure out why.

```
$time1 = '11/03/2013 15:28:00';
$time2 = '11/01/2013 15:39:00';

$hourdiff = round((strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2))/3600,2);
echo $hourdiff;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps day light savings come into play?

Comment: What time zone do you live in? Could there have been a switch to winter time on Novemer 3 in that zone?

Comment: ... Also the format of the date (is it 3rd Nov or Mar 11th?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is likely due to daylight saving time.

You could set the dates to UTC which removes this issue.

```
$time1 = '11/03/2013 15:28:00 UTC';
$time2 = '11/01/2013 15:39:00 UTC';

$hourdiff = round( ( strtotime( $time1 ) - strtotime( $time2 ) ) / 3600, 2 );
```

Comment: I didn't know about this function, I can't up-vote because I don't have a reputation yet. Thanks for this, daylight savings was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Must be related to daylight saving. I see according to Google daylight saving in the US ends on 2 Nov which could be why. Try this and see if you get the correct result:

```
$time1 = '11/05/2013 15:28:00 <br/>';
$time2 = '11/03/2013 15:39:00';
```

Comment: I tested this and you are correct, daylight savings was the problem. It didn't even cross my mind. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$diffHours = round(((strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2)) / 3600),2);
```

In your equation you are not rounding on total result

Thanks